# c# Entity Framework Eager Loading pulling in all children

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this **questionGroup** that looks something like this:

```
public class QuestionGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public QuestionGroupType Type { get; set; }

    public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

and the **question** model looks something like this:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionGroupId { get; set; }

    public QuestionGroup QuestionGroup { get; set; }
}
```

I have disabled **Lazy Loading** in my **DbContext** like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Default constructor
/// </summary>
public DatabaseContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
{

    // Disable Lazy Loading
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    // Write our SQL to the debug window
    this.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);

    // Increase the timeout
    this.Database.CommandTimeout = 10000;
}
```

Now, I have a **Repository** class that has a **List** method which looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all the entities
/// </summary>
/// <param name="includes">Option includes for eager loading</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IQueryable<T> List(params string[] includes)
{

    // Create a query
    IQueryable<T> query = this.dbEntitySet;

    // For each include, append to our query
    foreach (var include in includes)
        query = query.Include(include);

    // Return our query
    return query;
}
```

So that in theory I can send an array of **includes** to the **Repository** so that they can be **Eagerly loaded**.
Somewhere done the line I do this:

```
var models = await this._service.ListAllAsync("Questions");
```

Which I would expect to return my **QuestionGroups** and the child **Questions** for each group.
The problem is, it doesn't just do that, it will Get the **Question's** group and the groups Question and so on and so on.

like this:

> QuestionGroup > Questions > [0] > QuestionGroups > Questions

Does anyone know why and how to stop it?

---

### Update

Ok, so now I have enabled **Lazy loading** and I still get the same issue:

```
public class QuestionGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public QuestionGroupType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

A **QuestionGroup** has one navigational property: **Questions**

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionGroupId { get; set; }

    public QuestionGroup QuestionGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public virtual Criteria Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

A **Question** has 2 navigational properties: **Answers** and **Criteria**:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<State> States { get; set; }
}

public class Criteria
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public CriteriaType Type { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(100)] public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool SaveToDatabase { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<State> States { get; set; }
    public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

An **Answer** has one navigational property: **States**, and **Criteria** also has one navigational property which also happens to be **States**:

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CriteriaId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(100)] public string Name { get; set; }
    public TargetType Target { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
    public Criteria Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

A **State** has one navigational property, which is **Filter**:

```
public class Filter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(5)] public string Operator { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(255)] public string Expression { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string Field { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

and **Filters** have no navigational properties.
When I try to use **Lazy Loading**, I expect that only my navigation properties will be populated, but if I try to get the **QuestionGroup**, it will get the **Question** with all it's **Answers** and **Criteria**, which is fine, but it also get's the **QuestionGroup** too.

Comment: This is how eager loading works. You get all or nothing. What's the problem with that?

Comment: I get a stackoverflow

Comment: I guess you have in mind some sort of a serialization (json?) because so cannot happen in the query itself? If yes, you could solve it by using serializer options (like Newtonsoft Json.JsonSerializer `PreserveReferencesHandling`)

Answer (score 1):

You break the uni-directional navigation by replacing

> public QuestionGroup QuestionGroup { get; set; }

with

> public int QuestionGroupId { get; set; }

This allows you to query back to get the question group of the question, but not cause a circular reference. You can even encapsulate the query in a method.

> public QuestionGroup GetQuestionGroup();